# How to write an equal sign above a letter

Tags: symbols, accents

Just like in the picture, there's an equal sign above "I". I don't even know what to call it.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what the double bars above `I` signify. Are there instances of either a single bar or a triple bar above `I` (or any other letter)?

Comment: maybe you can use \stackrel{=}{I}

Answer (score 12):

I'd like to suggest that you load the `amsmath` package and write `\bar{\bar{I}}` -- in math mode, naturally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\bar{\bar{I}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `\overset{=}{I}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \Big( \overset{=}{I} - \Big.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Another way to do it is to place the equal sign as an accent with the `accents` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
\(\accentset{=}{I}\)
\end{document}
```